# How to set background color in floating child elements?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to assign a common background color for 2 elements that reside under the same container.

I have set `id` for both elements; `left` for the first element and `right` for the second element.
The left one has `float:left` and the right one has `float:right`, and both have width of `45%`. The container has width of `80%` and margin left and margin right set to `auto`.

When setting `background-color` on the container, neither child's background color changes, but when setting `background-color` on the left element it worked.

How to set background color for both child elements?

Comment: Don't use background-color in the children, only on the parent.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle or some code?

Comment: Use your browser's inspector tools... when you `float` elements, you remove them from the normal flow of the document. The height of your container will now be `0`, meaning there's no background to show.

Comment: #css-table {
 background-color:blue;
 margin-top:600px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 width:80%;
 clear:both;


}


#left {
 float:left;
 width:45%;

}

#right {
 float:right;
 width:45%;
 
}

Comment: rephrased for clarity, formatted

Answer (score 0):

When you `float` elements, they are removed from the normal document flow. Your container will now have a height of `0`, meaning there is no height visible for the background to be shown. To get around this, you can set `overflow:auto` on the container.

See this article on CSS floats for an explanation: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html